# Tell SVNKit not to store credentials or at least change the path

Tags: credentials, svnkit

Every time I connect to a repository the credentials are stored in the user's home folder under the .subversion directory (UNIX systems). Is there anyway not to do this, or at least specify another directory something like --config-dir option under the command line?

I made a little hack that is change temporarily the user.home java property, but this doesn't work on Windows.

Thanks in advance,

Rui

Comment: Run your code through a Java debugger, and find out where in the SVNKit code the credentials write is happening.  Then you can see if there a parameter or configuration option you can change.

Comment: I checked the source. It seems impossible. Maybe is something to include for future releases.

Comment: did you able to find any workaround for this?

Comment: Sorry for not being able to help :/ This was a long time ago and I'm not even on that project nor company anymore so I cannot really check it for you.

Answer (score 1):

One of the `createDefaultAuthenticationManager()` implementations allows this.

It is a static method in `org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNWCUtil`.

Here is the description from https://svnkit.com/javadoc/

> public static ISVNAuthenticationManager createDefaultAuthenticationManager(java.io.File configDir, java.lang.String userName, java.lang.String password, boolean storeAuth)
>
> Creates a default authentication manager that uses the provided configuration directory and user's credentials. The storeAuth parameter affects on using the auth storage.
>
> Parameters:
>  configDir - a new location of the run-time configuration area
>   userName - a user's name
>   password - a user's password
>   storeAuth - if true then the auth storage is enabled, otherwise disabled
>  Returns:
>   a default implementation of the credentials and servers configuration driver interface

So, you could do something like.

```
...set up repository...
File configDir = new File("MyFolder");
ISVNAuthenticationManager auth;
auth = SVNWCUtil.createDefaultAuthenticationManager( 
&nbsp;configDir, user, password, false );
repository.setAuthenticationManager(auth);
```